# How can I move application's window between virtual desktops in OS X?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I would like to move my application's window between OS X virtual desktops.

For example: to move window to currently active desktop.

Is there a way to do it with Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found answer by my self. This could be done by adjusting window behaviour.

```
let window = NSWindow...
```

Window is shown on all virtual desktops:

```
window.collectionBehavior = NSWindowCollectionBehavior.CanJoinAllSpaces
```

Window follows active virtual desktop:

```
window.collectionBehavior = NSWindowCollectionBehavior.MoveToActiveSpace
```