# Move window to active space

Tags: swift, macos

I have a small window that needs to be in the active space (macOS Swift)

One option would be to have that window in all the spaces. It seems that is not recommendable: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/collectionbehavior/1419120-movetoactivespace

Another approach is to move the window when the user changes to another space. I could find that in the documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419707-isonactivespace
Also this question: [How can I move application's window between virtual desktops in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495072/how-can-i-move-applications-window-between-virtual-desktops-in-os-x)

I am not sure if that is the right option. In any case, I cannot apply apply the documentation to the current window. self.view.window This is what I tried but if I change space the window remains in the first space. Probably there is something I do not understand or I am missing?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.window?.collectionBehavior = NSWindow.CollectionBehavior.canJoinAllSpaces
        self.view.window?.collectionBehavior = NSWindow.CollectionBehavior.moveToActiveSpace
}
```

Comment: Is `self.view.window` perhaps `nil` at that moment?

Comment: @matt Thank you. I tried to put the two lines of code inside a delay of 2 seconds and I see no difference. I also:  let finestra = self.view.window  print (finestra!) and it gives that to the console: <NSWindow: 0x600003e0c200>